# How to create a self signed cerficate using command prompt?

Tags: windows, ssl-certificate

Is there a way to create a self signed certificate in IIS in windows 2012 R2 using command prompt?
I went many documents, everywhere there is tutorial using Windows powershell but not using command prompt.
I do not have makecert utility installed in my system. Is there any other command or utility. 
I saw a selfssl utility but i am not sure whether it will work on windows 2012 RE server.

Comment: there are no built-in tools, as Microsoft and other vendors extensively move away from cmd to PowerShell. And why you can't use PowerShell? Any stopping reason?

Comment: No specific reason but just want to explore other options. i installed windows sdk which provided me makecert.exe, using which i can create a self signed certificate. But can anyone tell me what are the minimum required parameters to create using makecert and also once its completes and displays suceeded, where can i look for my certificate in my system?

Answer (score 3):

Try [certreq](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn296456.aspx) tool. Data are given in a form of inf file. The before mentioned link contains information about the file structure. [This](http://blogs.technet.com/b/pki/archive/2009/08/05/how-to-create-a-web-server-ssl-certificate-manually.aspx) link contains example inf file of an SSL certificate (could be of more help).

Then run

```
certreq -new your_inf_file.inf generated_req.req
```

As a side effect it will generate a self signed certificate in Certificate Enrollment Requests in the store you specified in the inf file. Just move the certificate to `My` store and also (because it is self signed) to `Trusted Root Certification Authorities`.

You can also use [xca](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xca/). It is a nice utility built on openssl which lets you create any certificates (self signed or any chain of CAs) and it is easy to use.

Comment: your solution is not correct, because it is not the right way to generate self-signed certificates. I added the correct link to AskDS blog that describes supported way to generate certs.

Comment: @CryptoGuy thanks for posting better link how to generate self signed certificates with certreq. BTW what is the `right` way to generate self sign certificates? :)

Comment: `right` is the one that is supported by Microsoft. In the case of certreq, the `right` way is the one provided in the AskDS blog. `New-SelfSignedCertificate` PS cmdlet is another `right` way. Alternatively, you can use `CertEnroll` COM interfaces which are supported by Microsoft.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't bother with `makecert` as it is deprecated. Instead, I would suggest you use PowerShell as it is the mainstream administration tool in Windows Server. Windows Server 2012 has a built-in cmdlet to generate self-signed certificates: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848633(v=wps.630).aspx

When Microsoft deprecated makecert tool, they enhanced the [certreq](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn296456.aspx) cmdline tool with the ability to generate self-signed certificates, though, with an overhead: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2012/08/14/rsa-key-blocking-is-here.aspx

Comment: What is the overhead? I did not find it in the blog post you posted. Maybe I just missed it.

Comment: overhead in INF file preparation, certreq INF-specific syntax and so on. PowerShell avoids all this by using named parameters (which can be explored by using autocompletion and built-in help susbsystem). I personally use certreq only where it matters (almost never).

Answer (score 0):

The article rsa-key-blocking-is-here.aspx moved here.

[rsa-key-blocking-is-here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-directory-services-team/rsa-key-blocking-is-here/ba-p/400077?msclkid=0130a2dfc11c11ec97746c52187f318d)